# What does the populate function in mongoose do?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean, meanjs

I don't understand the problem when i read http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. I don't fully understand what the `populate` function does. I picked it up from `meanjs` sample source code:

```
Article.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
if (err) {
  return res.status(400).send({
    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
  });
} else {
  res.json(articles);
}});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Article` document, you are storing userId of the users.

Now while querying `Article` document, with articles you want to get users for each then you can use populate.

Now when you access `articles[index].user`, then it will return object instead of `ObjectId` value (`_id` property of user).

Second argument defines that which field should be retrieved in `User` object. Here it is `displayName`. So it will retrieve `_id` and `displayName` of `User`. If you want to exclude _id you can specify "-_id displayName"

Comment: Thank you very much, it really usefull to me, have good day for you :)